# Twitter /2/users/:id/tweets returns 401 when using parameter start_time

Tags: api, twitter

I am calling this endpoint https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-users-id-tweets using OAuth 1.0a

The endpoint works perfectly fine without the start_time parameter. When I use the start_time like [https://api.twitter.com/2/users/[id]/tweets?start_time=2023-02-26T17:38:00Z](https://api.twitter.com/2/users/%5Bid%5D/tweets?start_time=2023-02-26T17:38:00Z), I get a 401 Unauthorized.

Things I tried:

- start_time with and without milliseconds
- different start_times from long ago to recent
- using start_time and end_time (no matter which constellation I get 401, also for only end_time)

What am I missing? Any tips?

Comment: I am using [Elevated](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#item0) access level and it support `OAuth 2.0 with PKCE`, `OAuth 1.0a` and `App only` Authentication methods. This level no problem to sue start_time and end_time. Do you `Essential` level? It may have  to limit  access.

Comment: @BenchVue I have elevated access. As I said, I only have the 401 with the parameter, not without. Which OAuth do you use if I may ask?

Comment: I got the token by `https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials` and use Stand Alone's API Key/Secret, then call that API with start_time.

Comment: It worked! Guess OAuth2 has more access rights. TY

Answer (score 0):

OAuth 1.0a does not allow start_time parameter. Switched to OAuth 2.0 and works now